# SQL CE query corresponding to a MYSQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server-ce

I use the following query through c# code to execute an update operation in MYSQL:

```
string query = "UPDATE Projects SET Manpower = CONCAT(Manpower," + "\'|" + manname + 
"\') WHERE Name=\'" + projname + "\';";
```

Later, there was a need to shift from MYSQL to SQL CE. On execution got the error:

```
The function is not recognized by SQL Server compact edition. 
[Name of function = CONCAT.Data type (if unknown) = ]
```

I realize that in SQL CE, the '+' operator is used for concatenation. But I haven't been able to get it right. Any idea on how to modify the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used the following query!

```
string query = "UPDATE Projects SET Manpower = Manpower+" + "\'|" + manname + "\' 
WHERE Name=\'" + projname + "\';";
```